# PHP Salt password encryption

Tags: php, mysql, hash, md5, salt

My client forgot password to login to the backend of the website that was developed by other developer who refused to help. Therefore, I went to SQL database to see if I could retrieve the password directly from there but it seems that password is encrypted. See below

> 3a0606b25e75eb6c1fed61886844832e

it would be easier if I knew how the password was encrypted so that I could just encrypt new password and add to SQL but when I looked at the code (in password changing PHP gile) there is something called salt_pass that encrypts the password of this website. See below code :

```
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {
$db = new database();
$option_uw = array(
    "table" => "users",
    "fields" => "password",
    "condition" => "id='{$_POST['id']}'"
);
$query_uw = $db->select($option_uw);
$rs_uw = $db->get($query_uw);
if ($rs_uw['password'] == trim(salt_pass($_POST['oldpassword']))) {
    $value_pw = array(
        "password" => trim(salt_pass($_POST['pass']))
    );
    $query_pw = $db->update("users", $value_pw, "id='{$_POST['id']}'");

    if ($query_pw == TRUE) {
        header("location:" . $baseUrl . "/back/user");
    }
}else{
    $_SESSION[_ss . 'msg_result'] = TRUE;
    header("location:" . $baseUrl . "/back/user/changepassword");
}
mysql_close();
}
```

Here is the `salt_pass` function

```
function salt_pass($pass) { 
     return md5("supapongherb.com" . $pass); 
}
```

Does anybody know how I can regenerate or encrypt the new password according to this code?

PS. the website is developed with MVC programming and I am really capable of it. Please let me know if you would like to see more file.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Look at the `insert` syntax and you should be able to figure out how the password is/was generated. It probably was hashed and you wont be able to de-hash it because hashing is not encrypting, it only goes one way.

Comment: I just found this function I am not sure what to do next. 
function salt_pass($pass) {
    return md5("supapongherb.com" . $pass);
}

Comment: Now you can generate a new password because you know the (outdated) hashing algorithm and the salt that was used. You don't even need to do it PHP. `update users set password = md5(concate("supapongherb.com", 'NEWPASSWORD')) where userid = ??`. something like that

Comment: You shouldn't just be giving out users passwords unless you know for certain that it's them. Just send them a reset link.

Comment: You should take the time to upgrade them from MD5 to something that is actually secure as well.

Comment: @badjuju The OP can `just encrypt new password and add to SQL`.

Comment: I just did encrypt the new password and changed the way it is encrypted. However, I think it is the system itself that is very old. The system does not seem to work properly but thank you trillion guys!

Comment: Yes, your system seems very insecure. `"id='{$_POST['id']}'` seems like it is awaiting a SQL injection. You should use parameterized queries.

Answer (score 5):

Let's clear a few things up

> but it seems that password is encrypted

First, your password is *hashed*, not encrypted. [There is a difference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4948322/fundamental-difference-between-hashing-and-encryption-algorithms). Namely that hashes are meant to be one-way. There's no way to look at a hash and just regenerate the password from that.

Second, they're using MD5. They're not actually salting anything, they're appending the same string to all passwords and THEN hashing it. MD5 is a [terrible way to hash because it's stupid easy to break](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/19906/is-md5-considered-insecure). This is the equivalent of securing your front door with a rubber band. It's not secure because you can make *millions of guesses a minute*. Yes it is that bad.

Third, with the function and the "salt" known, you can easy make a new password this way (via SQL because I'm not guessing what sort of screwy ORM they're using there)

```
UPDATE users
SET password = MD5(CONCAT('supapongherb.com', 'new_password_here'))
WHERE id = their_user_id_here
```

Fourth, switch to [password_hash](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php). Like now. Get rid of the rubber band and upgrade to a deadbolt, with rabid pitbulls behind it and a shotgun in your lap.